How to play audio from a Base64 encoded string obtained from API in Java
I am using this API to convert text to speech in java. The API returns a string in Base64 encoded. Below here is my attempt:
private static void playAudio(String audioString) {

        try {
            byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(audioString);

            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
            Clip song = AudioSystem.getClip();
            song.open(audioIn);
            song.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

audioString is the encoded string.
The problem is that I got the error: "Stream of unsupported format". I don't know if I have to configure any other things to make it work properly.
What is the correct way of doing it?

Are you passing "audioEncoding: 'MP3'" ? And did you check if Java supports MP3? Hint: It does not.

@ElliottFrisch If I change the audioCoding to WAV, I will get 400 error. Is it my mistake or the API actually does not support any other type? What is the solution here?
